# Psycopg2 type error when inserting with execute_batch

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to do a batch insert using psycopg2 into a postgres database. I am using %s and a list of tuples, but it's failing with the following error:

```
File ".../python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/extras.py", line 1183, in execute_batch
    sqls = [cur.mogrify(sql, args) for args in page]
  File ".../python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/extras.py", line 1183, in <listcomp>
    sqls = [cur.mogrify(sql, args) for args in page]
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Here's my code:

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        database='mydb',
        user='name',
        password='pass')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    query = "INSERT INTO my_table (tweet_id, user_id, time, text, 
        reply_to_user_id, reply_to_tweet_id, reply_to_handle, is_retweet, 
        is_quote, quote_usr_id, quote_usr_handle, quote_id, quote_text, 
        retweet_usr_id, retweet_usr_handle, retweet_id, longitude, latitude, 
        location, time_zone) VALUES (%s);"
    #vals are values to insert, a list of tuples
    vals = [(123, 123, datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 18, 17, 12, 33), 
        "'Some Text'", None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
        None, 1234, "'username'", 1234, None, None, "'Somewhere'", 
        "'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'"), 
        (321, 321, datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 18, 15, 43, 19), 
        "'More text'", 321, 321, "'person'", None, None, None, None, None,  
        None, None, None, None, None,None, "'faraway'", 
        "'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'")]
    psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cur,query,vals)
```

I have also tried replacing the Nones with "NULL" strings to no avail.

vals is a list of tuples, so it isn't the common problem from the [faq](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html) and [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524482/psycopg2-typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting) [stackoverflow posts.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863881/psycopg2-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting)

I'm hoping it's an issue with one of the types that I'm inserting, but am at a loss for which one. I've compared against the psycopg2 python to sql [datatype conversion chart](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters), and it seems like it should check out.

Comment: VALUES (%s,%s, .... %s) ?

Comment: 20 values, I think you want to explicitly pass number of values in your query.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I don't know how I missed that! If you answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Explicitly pass number of values into your query.

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    database='mydb',
    user='name',
    password='pass')
    cur = conn.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO my_table (tweet_id, user_id, time, text, 
    reply_to_user_id, reply_to_tweet_id, reply_to_handle, is_retweet, 
    is_quote, quote_usr_id, quote_usr_handle, quote_id, quote_text, 
    retweet_usr_id, retweet_usr_handle, retweet_id, longitude, latitude, 
    location, time_zone) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);"
#vals are values to insert, a list of tuples
vals = [(123, 123, datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 18, 17, 12, 33), 
    "'Some Text'", None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
    None, 1234, "'username'", 1234, None, None, "'Somewhere'", 
    "'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'"), 
    (321, 321, datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 18, 15, 43, 19), 
    "'More text'", 321, 321, "'person'", None, None, None, None, None,  
    None, None, None, None, None,None, "'faraway'", 
    "'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'")]
psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cur,query,vals)
```

Comment: Does this work for named parameters? Having in SQL `%(age)s` while using list of dictionaries as a `vals` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing queries (for UPSERT if it's necesseray), I advise you to write a function of type:

```
def execute_upsert(cur, table, champs, rows, champs_unique=None):
    """
        Fonction qui renvoie la requete pour execute_batch(cur, requete, list_rows) de psycopg2
        :param cur: cursor psycopg2
        :param table: Table postgresql, pour l'insertion
        :param champs: List ou Tuple des Champs de la table, pour les insertions
        :param rows: Tableau (list, tuple, generator) des lignes à insérer
        :param champs_unique: Si Upsert, on donne un tuple des champs d'unicité
    """

    def get_sql(t, col, c_u):
        """
            Fonction qui renvoie la requete pour execute_batch(cur, requete, list_rows) de psycopg2
            :param t: Table postgresql, pour l'insertion
            :param col: List ou Tuple des Champs de la table, pour les insertions
            :param c_u: Si Upsert, on donne un tuple des champs d'unicité
            :return: Retourne la Requête
        """
        sql_insert = f'INSERT INTO "{t}" ('
        champs_insertion = []

        for champ in col:
            sql_insert += f'"{champ}", '
            test_champ = "%s"
            champs_insertion.append(test_champ)

        if len(champs_insertion) > 1:
            c = str(tuple(champs_insertion)).replace("'", "")
            sql_insert = sql_insert[:-2] + f') VALUES {c} '
        else:
            c = "(" + str(champs_insertion[0]).replace("'", "") + ")"
            sql_insert = sql_insert[:-2] + f') VALUES {c} '

        if c_u is None:
            sql_insert += 'ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;'

        else:
            if champs_unique is not None:
                chu = "("
                for value in champs_unique:
                    chu += f'"{value}", '
                chu = f'{chu[:-2]})'
                sql_insert += f' ON CONFLICT {chu} DO UPDATE SET '
                for champ in champs:
                    if champ not in champs_unique:
                        sql_insert += f'"{str(champ)}" = excluded."{str(champ)}", '

                sql_insert = sql_insert[:-2] + ';'

            else:
                sql_insert += ';'

        return sql_insert

    execute_batch(cur, get_sql(table, champs, champs_unique), rows)
```

after is very simple :

```
execute_upsert(
    cur=cur,
    table=table_projets_colonnesprojet,
    champs=champs_table,
    rows=list_rows,
    champs_unique=("code_comptable",)
)
```

Comment: Not safe for SQL Injection attack.